# Time difference in days in OpenOffice Calc

Tags: function, date, openoffice-calc

I have a spreadsheet of bugs. In column `M`, I have the date the bug was logged, and in column `I`, I have the date the bug was closed. These are in the UK date format `DD/MM/YYYY`.

What I would like is a sum or function that works out the number of days elapsed between bug opened and closed/updated. But I cannot seem to work out how to do this or get my head around it.

I am currently using `=SUM(H60-G60)`, which doesn't seem to be working.

Answer (score 1):

```
DAYS(date_2; date_1)
```

Calculates the difference, in days, between two date values. Date_1 is the start date. Date_2 is the end date. If Date_2 is an earlier date than Date_1, the result is a negative number.